# What is a circular motion around a object called when filming?

Tags: video, camera, filming

You know that camera technique when the camera operator usually have a steadicam and runs/walks around a person.

I'm trying to learn how to do that with my homemade glidecam but it is so hard. it would be nice to find a tutorial but I don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a kind of tracking shot known as an orbit. Here is a product video for the Digital Juice Orbit Dolly, which is a piece of equipment that can be used to achieve this effect:

Comment: Thank you. Going to tell my friend Google about this. He will be excited :D

Comment: @PhilvanKleur It was a product video from a video equipment company. I've updated the link with one that is still available, and clarified the purpose of the link in my answer.

Comment: @NReilingh thanks very much. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

It is known as panning, from the word "panoramic" - googling will throw up many tutorials on this.

[An example at the slrlounge](http://www.slrlounge.com/panning-tutorial).

Comment: I don't think that is what I mean. I mean when the camera circles around an object.